# ¿Son aceptadas las preguntas SEO?

Tags: discusión

Hacer preguntas referentes a Search Engine Optimization (SEO) ¿son aceptadas?. De acuerdo con el artículo oficial publicado en [¿Que tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar - Centro de Ayuda - Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Creo conveniente que se discuta sobre ello por que son preguntas que incurren a la investigación y tienen un punto de vista de objetivo. En cambio, no encuentro etiqueta alguna que refiera a ello y he ahí mi duda.

**Preguntas como:**

- ¿Cuál es la mejor práctica para optimizar un sitio?
- ¿Cómo usar correctamente el separador del título? «-» o «|»
- ¿Cómo optimizar una imagen sin perder calidad?
- ¿Cómo usar RewriteCond en el .htaccess para comprimir contenido?
- ¿Cuál es la importancia de sitemap.xml?

Todo este tipo de preguntas es publicada originalmente en [Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Me gustaría conocer objetivamente el por qué si o no sería considerado incluir dicho contenido en el StackOverflow en Español, si existe alternativa o consideración sobre el tema.

Comment: Considera agregarla como wiki en el tema [Encuesta: definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/encuesta-definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio?cb=1) y votemos por ahi. Creo que sería mejor centralizar todos los temas en el mismo post

Comment: @CésarBustíos ¿cómo la hago wiki? o ¿sólo añado la respuesta y borro esta pregunta?

Comment: Simplemente crea una respuesta y abajo a la derecha márcala como wiki

Comment: @CésarBustíos ¡Listo! ¿consideras que es mejor que borre esta publicación?

Comment: Mas que borrarla consideraría cerrarla para quede registrada, ya di mi voto

Comment: @CésarBustíos Listo, la voté como contenido duplicado.